# PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

I'm using [Zendesk php class](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/blob/master/src/Zendesk/API/Attachments.php), and the following function is used to delete attachments.

```
/**
 * Delete one or more attachments by token or id
 * $params must include one of these:
 *        'token' - the token given to you after the original upload
 *        'id' - the id of the attachment
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @throws MissingParametersException
 * @throws ResponseException
 * @throws \Exception
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function delete(array $params) {
    if(!$this->hasAnyKey($params, array('id', 'token'))) {
        throw new MissingParametersException(__METHOD__, array('id', 'token'));
    }
    $endPoint = Http::prepare(($params['token'] ? 'uploads/'.$params['token'] : 'attachments/'.$params['id']).'.json');
    $response = Http::send($this->client, $endPoint, null, 'DELETE');
    if ($this->client->getDebug()->lastResponseCode != 200) {
        throw new ResponseException(__METHOD__);
    }
    $this->client->setSideload(null);
    return true;
}
```

According to the comments, either the token or ID is required when running this function.

I have tried using an id

```
$attachment = $client->attachments()->delete(array('id'=>'1187146218','token'));
```

However it keeps trowing exception

```
  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: token in /home/adam/web/srv11/public_html/vendor/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/src/Zendesk/API/Attachments.php on line 106
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zendesk\API\ResponseException' with message 'Response to Zendesk\API\Attachments::delete is not valid. Call $client->getDebug() for details' in /home/adam/web/srv11/public_html/vendor/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/src/Zendesk/API/Attachments.php:109
Stack trace:
#0 /home/adam/web/srv11/public_html/functions/support-attachment-delete.php(15): Zendesk\API\Attachments->delete(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/adam/web/srv11/public_html/vendor/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php/src/Zendesk/API/Attachments.php on line 109
```

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: either token or id is required....you are passing an array with 2 indexes but only 1 value.  You could try removing `,'token'` or changing it to `array('id'=>'1187146218','token'=>null)`  But I think the undefined index is that token peice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you have this written

```
array('id'=>'1187146218','token')
```

actually gives an array like this:

```
array('id'=>'1187146218', 0 => 'token')
```

so there is no 'token' index. This should work if you just change to

```
$attachment = $client->attachments()->delete(array('id'=>'1187146218','token' => NULL));
```

Comment: Can you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295877/webclient-too-many-automatic-redirections-were-attempted